# Alexa Deploy - ask deploy tries to recreate user for every deploy? Response is invalid in text test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to setup my Amazon Alexa right now and it's been giving me some troubles. Here are the steps I've done and the problems I've run into.

I installed the AWS CLI and ASK (Alexa Skill Kit) CLI

I ran `aws configure` with an IAM user on AWS

I then ran `ask deploy --profile <aws configure username>`

For every permission error I had while running this command, I added the permission to the already existing IAM user I created. The command also created it's own IAM role which I had to delete each time I re-ran the command.

Once I got the command to work once, a Lambda function and Alexa Skill were created for me. Yay!

However, the Alexa skill has to be reconfigured with each `ask deploy` run and the `ask deploy` command tries to recreate a user every time I run it. This isn't *terrible* because the `ask deploy` command still updates the Alexa Skill. However, I haven't been able to get my Alexa Skill working at all with text input and I'm wondering if it's an issue with how I setup the ASK.

Trying to create a new user:

```
-------------------- Update Skill Project --------------------
Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.6eb4f796-8a23-4745-8d3a-5d2b2af5166e
Skill deployment finished.
Model deployment finished.
Create role error.
EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name ask-lambda-EKO already exists
```

The error I get when trying the Service Simulator with text is:

`The response is invalid`

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

I've enabled stack traving in the Lambda function and my requests in the text test in the Alexa Skill are returning 200 OK statuses in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure skill.json and .ask/config like this:

skill.json:

```
"apis": {
  "custom": {
    "endpoint": {
      "sourceDir": "lambda/custom"
    }
  }
}
```

.ask/config:

```
"apis": {
  "custom": {
    "endpoint": {
      "uri": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:function:lambdaName"
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://blog.josequinto.com/2018/04/25/deploy-alexa-skill-using-already-created-lambda-function-and-role/#Deploy-the-skill